# How can I require reindexing in magento backend

Tags: index, indexer

I made a custom module and I want the user to be prompted to reindex a certain index table. How can I show this prompt progmatically?

[image]

Comment: have you create your custom indexer class file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to notify about requiring a reindex, it is enough to set this index to invalid/require update, magento will then show it automatically.